# Proving question on sets

Tags: functions

I am unable to understand this question. I have to say whether its true of false and then prove it but I can't proceed with the question unless I understand it.

> Let $S$ be the set of stars in our galaxy. There is exactly the same
>   number of subsets of stars in our galaxy as there are functions
>   $f:S\rightarrow\{\alpha,\beta\}$

Comment: There's a standard way in mathematics to prove that there is an equal number of things: show that you can link every subset up with a function in a [one-to-one correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\{\alpha, \beta\}$ is in bijection with the set $\{\text{yes, no}\}$.

Given a set $A \subseteq S$ of stars, can you think of any way to encode information about $A$ into a function from $S$ to the set $\{\text{yes, no}\}$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

This is one of the many functions from $S = \{ s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_6 \}$ to $\{ \alpha, \beta \}$:

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
s_i \in S & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & s_5 & s_6 \\
\hline
f(s_i) & \beta & \beta & \alpha & \beta & \alpha & \alpha
\end{array}

This is a subset $A$ of $S$: $A = \{ s_1, s_2, s_4 \}$

Here is another function:

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
s_i \in S & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & s_5 & s_6 \\
\hline
f(s_i) & \beta & \alpha & \alpha & \alpha & \alpha  & \beta
\end{array}

This is another subset $A$ of $S$: $A = \{ s_1, s_6 \}$